# DocuSign API : Agent recipient does not have an option to decline the envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working with `DocuSign API` and sending an envelope to agent using agent tag. Agent is able to send and complete the document but there is no option to decline the envelope. I want the agent to have an option to decline it. How I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the `Agent` recipient that you are adding to the envelope does not have any signature or initial tabs configured for them, then they are not taking any action on the envelope and hence can not sign the envelope or decline to sign.  The same is true for any `CarbonCopy` (cc) recipients, which never take an action on an envelope and hence never have the ability to decline (they simple receive a copy).

So to resolve, if you want your `Agent` recipient to be able to decline an envelope, they need to have at least one "action" tag configured for them.  The action tab can be a signature tab, initial tab, or anything else that requires their input - such as a checkbox, data field, etc.

Comment: Thanks Ergin. I looked at the rest api documentation and the agent tag does not have tabs tag as child (Signer has tabs tag). I tried to add tabs tag under agent in my code and test but it did not work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm that probably means that the other types of recipients can decline the envelope but not `Agents`.  I'll look around and try to confirm but that might be the case...

Comment: A recipient of type "Agent" cannot have tabs assigned to them.  From page 111 of the REST API guide:  "Tabs are associated with a specific recipient and are only used by the recipient types In Person Signers and Signers."

Comment: Thanks Kim. We dont have any requirement to have tabs for Agent. We have a requirement for agent to decline the request. Currently this is not there. I have looked at features/settings in the portal and I have not found any. Is there anyway our agents can decline requests? or would it be a manual that the agent has to send an email telling why they can not send the request to customer.